# Modifying site url to show country code instead of language code for a single country for one particular language alone in multilingual multisitesetup

Tags: sxa, multilingual, multisite, sxa-jss

We have a requirement where the default language code in the url has to be replaced with custom language code. For example [www.abcd.com/de](http://www.abcd.com/de) should be changed as [www.abcd.com/deu](http://www.abcd.com/deu).
Our sitecore instance is a multisite multilingual setup where we want to do the above change for one particular country-language only.
Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore uses System languages when you define a new language in Sitecore.

**That is why Step #1: Create a new culture `deu` and register it in Windows**

```
// This example demonstrates the System.Globalization.Culture-
// AndRegionInfoBuilder Register method.
// Compile this code example with a reference to sysglobl.dll.
// reference to MSDN for custom culture
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
class Sample
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        //var c = new CultureInfo("deu");
        // cs = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).OrderBy(n => n.EnglishName);

        CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder cib = null;
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Create and explore the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder...\n");
            cib = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder(
                                 "deu", CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);

            // Populate the new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder object with culture information.
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
            cib.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(ci);

            // Populate the new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder object with region information.
            RegionInfo ri = new RegionInfo("DE");
            cib.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(ri);

            // Display some of the properties of the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder object.
            Console.WriteLine("CultureName:. . . . . . . . . . {0}", cib.CultureName);
            Console.WriteLine("CultureEnglishName: . . . . . . {0}", cib.CultureEnglishName);
            Console.WriteLine("CultureNativeName:. . . . . . . {0}", cib.CultureNativeName);
            Console.WriteLine("GeoId:. . . . . . . . . . . . . {0}", cib.GeoId);
            Console.WriteLine("IsMetric: . . . . . . . . . . . {0}", cib.IsMetric);
            Console.WriteLine("ISOCurrencySymbol:. . . . . . . {0}", cib.ISOCurrencySymbol);
            Console.WriteLine("RegionEnglishName:. . . . . . . {0}", cib.RegionEnglishName);
            Console.WriteLine("RegionName: . . . . . . . . . . {0}", cib.RegionName);
            Console.WriteLine("RegionNativeName: . . . . . . . {0}", cib.RegionNativeName);
            Console.WriteLine("ThreeLetterISOLanguageName: . . {0}", cib.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName);
            Console.WriteLine("ThreeLetterISORegionName: . . . {0}", cib.ThreeLetterISORegionName);
            Console.WriteLine("ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName: {0}", cib.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName);
            Console.WriteLine("ThreeLetterWindowsRegionName: . {0}", cib.ThreeLetterWindowsRegionName);
            Console.WriteLine("TwoLetterISOLanguageName: . . . {0}", cib.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
            Console.WriteLine("TwoLetterISORegionName: . . . . {0}", cib.TwoLetterISORegionName);
            Console.WriteLine();            
            // Register the custom culture.
            Console.WriteLine("Register the custom culture...");
            cib.CultureEnglishName = "Euro Union";
            cib.CultureEnglishName = "Euro Union";
            cib.Register();

            // Display some of the properties of the custom culture.
            Console.WriteLine("Create and explore the custom culture...\n");
            ci = new CultureInfo("deu");

            Console.WriteLine("Name: . . . . . . . . . . . . . {0}", ci.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("EnglishName:. . . . . . . . . . {0}", ci.EnglishName);
            Console.WriteLine("NativeName: . . . . . . . . . . {0}", ci.NativeName);
            Console.WriteLine("TwoLetterISOLanguageName: . . . {0}", ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
            Console.WriteLine("ThreeLetterISOLanguageName: . . {0}", ci.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName);
            Console.WriteLine("ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName: {0}", ci.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName);

            Console.WriteLine("\nNote:\n" +
                "Use the example in the Unregister method topic to remove the custom culture.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Once the culture is created: **Step #2 you should be able to add new language inside Content Editor.** Sitecore>System>Languages